# MATLAB - error using struct for mmreader

Tags: matlab

I am trying to use mmreader to upload a video into MATLAB. I am trying to follow the example in the documentation, however at the line

```
mov(1:nFrames) = struct('cdata',zeros(vidHeight,vidWidth,3,'uint8'),'colormap',[]);
```

I get the following error:

```
??? The following error occurred converting from struct to mmreader: Error using ==> which Argument must contain a string.

Error in ==> VIDEO2 at 16 mov(1:nFrames) = struct('cdata', zeros(vidHeight, vidWidth, 3, 'uint8'),'colormap',[]);
```

Any ideas what may be wrong?  Here is the code I have written:

```
xyloObj = mmreader('xylophone.mpg'); 
nFrames = xyloObj.NumberOfFrames; 
vidHeight = xyloObj.Height; 
vidWidth = xyloObj.Width; 

%// Preallocate movie structure. 
mov(1:nFrames) = struct('cdata', zeros(vidHeight, vidWidth, 3, 'uint8'), ... 
                'colormap', []); 

%// Read one frame at a time. 
for k = 1 : nFrames 
    mov(k).cdata = read(xyloObj, k); 
end 

%// Size a figure based on the video's width and height. 
hf = figure; 
set(hf, 'position', [150 150 vidWidth vidHeight]) 

%// Play back the movie once at the video's frame rate. 
movie(hf, mov, 1, xyloObj.FrameRate);
```

Comment: It seems like `move` is already declared as `mmreader` objects. Why do you want to overwrite it? Maybe it is still in memory from the last run? In this case you could run `clear move;` first... I hope I got the situation right.

Comment: Just a side note... use VideoReader or VideoWriter.

Comment: Hi there well I'm just trying to use the code given in the documentation however I get the error at struct. I want to play my video in matlab but I'm stuck on the first frame. The reason I'm using mum reader is because. Have an older version of matlab. The code I am sung is;

Comment: xyloObj = mmreader('xylophone.mpg');

nFrames = xyloObj.NumberOfFrames;
vidHeight = xyloObj.Height;
vidWidth = xyloObj.Width;

% Preallocate movie structure.
mov(1:nFrames) = ...
    struct('cdata', zeros(vidHeight, vidWidth, 3, 'uint8'),...
           'colormap', []);

% Read one frame at a time.
for k = 1 : nFrames
    mov(k).cdata = read(xyloObj, k);
end

% Size a figure based on the video's width and height.
hf = figure;
set(hf, 'position', [150 150 vidWidth vidHeight])

% Play back the movie once at the video's frame rate.
movie(hf, mov, 1, xyloObj.FrameRate);

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your error because `mmreader` has been removed in my release of MATLAB.  Try using `VideoReader` instead.  Simply change `mmreader` to `VideoReader` and your code should (hopefully) work... at least it did on my computer!